# Python PIL image to text not working properly

Tags: python, image, tesseract, python-imaging-library

Below is my python script to read text on image. but its not working properly as latter `t` is read as `+` or `f`.I want to know how to deal with this issue?
I have also attached the file i am trying to read.

```
import tesserocr
from PIL import Image

print tesserocr.tesseract_version()  # print tesseract-ocr version
print tesserocr.get_languages()  # prints tessdata path and list of available languages

image = Image.open('test.png')
#print tesserocr.image_to_text(image)  # print ocr text from image
# or
print tesserocr.file_to_text('test.png')
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just have a run with `Tesseract 4.0.0 alpha` in command line with result below.

- `tesseract PILtoText.png PILtoText_out.txt -c preserve_interword_spaces=1 --psm 3 --oem 3`

> In a regulatory document filed with the SEC today, Adobe announced
>   that chief technology officer Kevin Lynch would be taking his leave as
>   of this coming friday.
>
> On March 18, 2013, Kevin Lynch resigned from his position as executive
>   vice president, chief technology officer, of Adobe Systems
>   Incorporated, effective March 22, 2013, to pursue other opportunities
>   the filing reads.Lynch, who came to the company in 2005 during its
>   acquisition of Macromedia, led Adobe's charge into some of the more
>   cutting-edge areas of technology, including multiscreen computing,
>   cloud computing, and social media.
>
> for ages, Adobe had been rooted in the workflows of the print design
>   community; Lynch was responsible for the company's shift into web
>   publishing, starting with Dreamweaver. He also oversaw Adobe's
>   research and experience design teams and was, as Adobe puts it, in
>   charge of "shaping Adobe's long- term technology vision and focusing
>   innovation across the company during a transformative time."
>
> Rumors around the web have pinpointed Apple as Lynch's next
>   destination, and it's not an entirely nonsensical rumor. Adobe's
>   transition to web technologies has been nothing if not profitable.
>   Apple, still a giant in consumer hardware, could use a helping hand
>   when it comes to multiscreen fluidity, social media, and web-based
>   software.

The result showed the text image is correctly recognized except the upper case `F` converted to `f`. For instance, **F**riday to **f**riday in the first paragraph.

If you are using `Tesseract 3.x`, would suggest to upgrade it to `Tesseract 4.0` for improving the OCR result.

Comment: @sachin have you checked the answer above?